# how to read principal id from jmeter load test task ARM template

Tags: azure, jmeter, load-testing

I'm looking to find out a way to read  value once I assign system managed identity to azure load testing resource in arm template. The documentation show below, can anyone help how to get  from ARM template deployment? Should it be part of output variables?

I need to read  value in next azure task, to grant the GET permissions to KV.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-testing/how-to-use-a-managed-identity?tabs=arm

```
When the resource is created, it gets the following additional properties:

JSON

Copy
"identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned",
    "tenantId": "<TENANTID>",
    "principalId": "<PRINCIPALID>"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the principalId
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `principalId`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.identity.principalId`
   - other fields can be left intact
3. That's it, the JSON Extractor will extract the value of the `principalId` property and store it into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html), you will be able to access it as `${principalId` later on where required

[image]

More information:

- [JSONPath: Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: sorry if my question is not clear, I have below tasks, 

1) ARM Template task that creates Load test resource and outputs system managed identity
2) read system managed identity from task 1 and assign policy to Key Vault1 (KV1) in azure power shell
3) AzureLoad test task that configures load test and pass the secrets from KV1

I'm unable to find an option on how to read output from task1 in task2 ( Azure powershell)

Comment: I found what I want. The option  deploymentOutputs: 'armOutputs' was missing from previous task and I was unable to get objectid in next task from previous task. I can read the object id in next task .